# Wanted: Help translating MSSQLSvr Recursive Query to MySQL SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I see the new MySQL can do recursive queries! Yahoo! Can someone help me translate this so I can see it work on MySQL V8?

```
WITH gov AS (
    SELECT 1 AS level, * FROM gov_unit where parent_id is null
  UNION ALL
   SELECT gov.level+1 AS level, gov_unit.* FROM gov_unit 
     INNER JOIN gov ON (gov_unit.parent_id = gov.id)
) SELECT * FROM gov;
```

Apparently, the MySQL syntax for "SELECT 1 AS level" is a little different.

Here is the sample table from my favorite book "Pocket Guide to SQL":

```
create table gov_unit (
  id      integer NOT NULL,
  parent_id   integer DEFAULT 3,
  name        varchar(10),
  type        varchar(8),
  constraint gov_unit_pk 
    primary key (id),
  constraint gov_unit_type_chk
    check (type in ('County','Township','City','State')),
    constraint gov_unit_loop
            foreign key (parent_id)
            references gov_unit(id)
) engine=innodb;
```

Here is some sample data:

```
insert into gov_unit values (3,null,'Michigan','State');
insert into gov_unit values (2,3,'Alger','County');
insert into gov_unit values (1,2,'Munising','City');
insert into gov_unit values (4,2,'Munising','Township');
insert into gov_unit values (5,2,'Au Train','Township');
insert into gov_unit values (6,3,'Baraga','County');
insert into gov_unit values (7,3,'Ontonagon','County');
insert into gov_unit values (8,7,'Interior','Township');
insert into gov_unit values (9,3,'Dickinson','County');
insert into gov_unit values (10,3,'Gogebic','County');
insert into gov_unit values (11,3,'Delta','County');
insert into gov_unit values (12,11,'Masonville','Township');
```

Comment: `SELECT 1 AS level, *` should be `SELECT 1 AS level, gov_unit.*`

Comment: This should basically work in MySQL . . . Versions 8+, that is.

Comment: OK, I made that change and now it is complaining that sqlpocket.gov does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems:
(1) I needed say gov_unit.* instead of * (thanks Madhur).
(2) I needed to change "with gov" to "with recursive gov".
Now it works!